# "Missing terminator" error

Tags: powershell

I'm using PS 2.0 on Windows 7, and can't figure out how to bypass this error.

I tried the exact code in Win 10 and it works as it should.

[image: ISE Screenshot]

Comment: You have escape character (`) after menu 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are escaping the double quote in the top, using backtick (`)
Try removing that backtick, then it should be normal.

Like so:

```
Write-host "Benchmarks menu V1.0"
```

Also, notice how the color bleeds over all of your code, below that line. Its a nice tool to figure out where your typos are located :)

Comment: On a second notice, i encourage you to read up on the backtick escape character, you would find that very useful in the future, when needing to make tabs(\`t) or Carriage-Returns(\`r\`n). Check it out on SS64 here:
https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html